# TensorFlow, reshaping in CNNs confusion

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I've seen this doubt posted several times but haven't got to any answers, at least of my particular confusion, as to how does reshaping work and why is it necessary. I'll try to be brief and to the point.

So, I've read in TensorFlow documentation that, when you are implementing a CNN, before inputting your data into your Convolution layer is necessary to reshape the data because the Convolution layer takes a 4D tensor, rather than just a list of elements (your downloaded training data).

The output of the Convolution-Pooling process is also a 4D tensor. Which is fed into the Flatten layer. Now...the Flatten layer, used to receive that same list elements that was necessary to reshape before passing it to the convolution. But, how come either thing works for the Flatten layer? It was receiving a list of items (which can't be fed directly to the convolution) and is now receiving a 4D tensor.

So if there is no convolution the Flatten layer receives not-reshaped data, if there is convolution-pooling it receives a 4D tensor, and then it outputs the same thing?

I hope I was clear enough as to what my confusion is, and hope someone is able to take some time to shed some light on my doubts.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

The input data to Convolution Neural Network (CNN) will look like the following picture. We are assuming that our data is a collection of images.

[image]

You always have to give a `4D` array as input to the CNN. So input data has a shape of `(batch_size, height, width, channels)`. Incase of `RGB` image would have a channel of `3` and the `greyscale` image would have a channel of `1`.

The output of the CNN is also a `4D` array. Where batch size would be the same as input batch size but the other 3 dimensions of the image might change depending upon the values of `filter`, `kernel size` and `padding` we use

Let’s look at the following code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Dense, Flatten

model=tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, input_shape=(10,10,3)))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10))
model.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 10, 10, 64)        256       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 5, 5, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 1600)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 10)                16010     
=================================================================
Total params: 16,266
Trainable params: 16,266
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Thought it looks like out input shape is `3D`, but you have to pass a `4D` array at the time of fitting the data which should be like `(batch_size, 10, 10, 3)`. Since there is no batch size value in the input_shape argument, we could go with any batch size while fitting the data.

The output shape for `Conv2D` and `MaxPool2D` are `(None, 10, 10, 64)`, `(None, 5, 5, 64)` respectively. The first dimension represents the batch size, which is `None` at the moment. Because the network does not know the batch size in advance. Once you fit the data, `None` would be replaced by the batch size you give while fitting the data.

We can simply add a convolution layer at the top of another convolution layer since the output dimension of convolution is the same as it’s input dimension.

We usually add the `Dense` layers at the top of the convolution layer to classify the images. However input data to the dense layer `2D` array of shape `(batch_size, units)`. And the output of the convolution layer is a `4D` array.

Thus we have to change the dimension of output received from convolution layer to a `2D` array.We can do it by inserting a `Flatten` layer on top of the Convolution layer. Flatten layer squash the `3` dimensions of an image to a `single` dimension. Now we only have a `2D` array of shape `(batch_size, squashed_size)`, which is acceptable for dense layers.

***Note***: We should always add `Flatten` layer just before `Dense` layer in the network.

In case of simply network you can start network with `Flatten` layer, since there is no convolution required.

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])
```

Comment: thank you so much for your thorough response! Some things I'm still al ittle on the fence about. For instance: for a simple network, the input shape for the Flatten layer would be [batch_size, height, width], correct? And in case of a CNN, the Flatten layer gets a [batch_size, height, width, number_of_convolutions]...is that about right?